# Website is showing someone else's

Tags: dns

I have a website that is hosted by Netlify, using Cloudflare DNS.

I completely forgot about the site so thought I would visit it, only to find out that it's not my site. It's something to do with chess.

Yes, the URL is correct. I've had a look in Netlify and their subdomain works fine, just not my custom domain name.

I've gone to namecheap and everything looks fine there, no red flags. Cloudflare also looks fine. The site is deployed by Github PR merges and I can confirm nothing strange there either.

The who is record also looks fine, I can see the Cloudflare nameservers are there.

What could be the reason I am seeing someone elses website? A DNS issue?

NB: There has been no unauthorized access to any accounts.

I can share the website as well as the Netlify subdomain if that helps and is not frowned upon.

I have a CNAME record pointing to the Netlify subdomain and the A record points to the IP address of the server.

Answer (score 1):

So I looked again at the records in Cloudflare. The IP address seemed off and I have no idea how I got that IP address. Having looked through Netlify's docs again, it says to create an A record pointing to their load balancer.

I did that and can now see my site again. I don't know if there was a change because that IP used to work but again, I have no idea what IP address it was.